# How to update a dialog box via SetDlgItemText within a function and have it take effect immediately in windows?

Tags: c++, windows

If I call SetDlgItemText() to update the value of a dialog text it seems to only be updated when the function returns.  I'm using it to update a status message informing the user of the current progress mid function so I would like it to be updated immediately.

If this can not be done, is there something else I can do that would perform the same results?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a dialog box that when the user hits a button it begins processing data.  I would like to update the status section of that dialog box with as each section of the data is process instead of at the very end.

Comment: After ending of processing function?

Comment: Inside of DialogProc i have a code which is called when the button is hit, it's inside of there that I am calling the SetDlgitemText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Processing function is not allowing to call the OnPaint message of the window to which you are setting the message. You can move the processing function to a thread so that main thread handles the UI messages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have never really done anything with threads yet, but this sounds like a good time to start learning :)